# Pick multiple generic inheritance within typescript type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I constructed a Typescript type named `AdditinalAttributes` which accepts a generic.
The type will return the **first condition** that matches.

I would want that the type will return the **sum** of the matching conditions.

Example:

- Current = `AdditinalAttributes<'number'>` → `TypeableAttributes`
- Target = `AdditinalAttributes<'number'>` → `TypeableAttributes & NumericAttributes`

Relevant Code:

```
type TypeableInputs = 'number' | 'text'
type DropdownInputs = ''
type NumericInputs  = 'number'

type AdditinalAttributes<T> = (

    T extends TypeableInputs ? 
        TypeableAttributes :

    T extends DropdownInputs ? 
        DropdownAttributes : 

    T extends NumericInputs  ? 
        NumericAttributes  :

    { }
)
```

Comment: You are saying "sum" but you mean "intersection" (An intersection is more like a product than a sum).  Could you change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the output to be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the relevant types, and because the input types are keylike, you can build a helper type whose properties are automatically what you want:

```
type InputToAttributeMap =
    Record<TypeableInputs, TypeableAttributes> &
    Record<DropdownInputs, DropdownAttributes> &
    Record<NumericInputs, NumericAttributes>
```

This uses [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype), which means "an object type with keys of type `K` and values of type `V`".  By intersecting these together we can avoid [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  The `InputToAttributeMap` type is equivalent to:

```
type InputToAttributeMap = {
    number: TypeableAttributes & NumericAttributes;
    text: TypeableAttributes;
    "": DropdownAttributes;
}
```

Then your `AdditionalAttributes` type just needs to [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) this mapping type:

```
type AdditionalAttributes<K extends keyof InputToAttributeMap> =
    InputToAttributeMap[K]
```

Let's test it:

```
type Target = AdditionalAttributes<"number">
//type Target = TypeableAttributes & NumericAttributes
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOE4CMA2EAgmGFMLgK6QDOyA3gFDIvJwBcyNZoA5owF9GoSLEQoAIlAD2mACbSA7iBI8qtBs1a5O3ciH5CR0eEmQA5SgFtowBKvLqIdJq2QJdPA4MaMwWFAxsPEIASRBMajoAXmQAchBrXGg45AAfeMgADzA4vwDkKVkFZXDIsBj4vP9sC2tbBDKo5FiEpJTfGpQmsFRpBwpqCABZOEwWrRYAJQgEaSg5AB4gnAIIHpoAGjQAkOJSRyGaAD5kADJJ5Bm5hcWi+SUQDe37kpUDwdpTi7dr+aXLDZyI0IlFtoCGgMnCdOgUAKIAR0owAAbi0GMgANoAaWQoGQAGsIOhpDBkD0+lChqNMABdTgU-ofJw0nG05ACADcjAA9AAqZBdZCI5Fo2KuViJKzJKCcFZ7KkaM51IF2RXOblubJgOW7Nbqmia1gAImNnFejwN3IEyD5PNhtSIcjkwDAwGkIDg+ANi1xEByEBAcjoRJJZMZ6ppp2ilwjzOpYzZDsCcCgvAgYHRTpdbo9Xp9xqlMuNx15PKFqFT6czsXl+vjSpVkIbziAA)

Answer (score 0):

In case what you actually want is an *intersection* of your attributes types (as suggested by @jcalz), besides his simple solution, we can also adapt the below one which was for a *union*: simply build the intersection directly, but instead of having potentially `never` members, they would be `unknown` (otherwise any non matching condition busts the output type as `never`):

```
type Extends2<T, I, A> = T extends I ? A : unknown

type AdditinalAttributes4<T> =
  Extends2<T, TypeableInputs, TypeableAttributes>
  & Extends2<T, DropdownInputs, DropdownAttributes>
  & Extends2<T, NumericInputs, NumericAttributes>
```

Note that with this solution, in case the generic does not match any condition, the type outputs `unknown`, i.e. it accepts any type. This is also what happens with the original type in the question (as `{}`).

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEMBGAbCBJAdmArsAzlALxQDkmOAtkhAE6lQA+ZwEAHsKQFCiRQAitAPZgAJkIDumLLgLEy3XtAByVOgEsAxjLyF55KjXpce8WPGRoAgsGC11SPBEIkA3lAQAuKBWp0A3FBI3r5GgZohhnRQAL6mfIIi4lI2dg5OLlDuwT5RtIGikX60sfEqavaaqfaOrJnZRWFQEbnFgRCN0XFlUFaiourA6pgIKNXpdQA8MAB88gAUJlDLsFDsrJiihHCQlhjYulAA-FBcK+fmu6gQ47XOUJ5LKzBrHBCbhIliktIHcidnC7LL7JTC3DIPU6A5YvdbvLZQVSUDTaP56AFA5ZIlHgurLR7QrKlACUJjQwB8OT6AyGIzGthqGUmBmKpBmXEwSHk7i8UAAjAAaILeQXNEWxKAAeklUAAygALIQ4FCiHxCCnyhAAN2gNHeUCEAGsECAoPNSBAGOpCLQIABHHDqW2q4aIipaXHOUk9ACibw+ACZpkL0EKrHMSLD-Qj0MdepCcJhDZgfiYlL1+oNhqNPfgACzTCOAv0bLZBmBCnaIa46AiVizXXPs5YAMigJfh+HLQpBP1r+B7wm+KQZE2czagbY7geDbuRlX7QuxlSbZIgFM5Ae81KzdNzBZZRjZHKQAe5HhFQpyopaoo6-Il0qgAHljSAT2e3Bf+VfL2KHzEUoygAYgg6goIQCCEOwkCaKwhRQAACkOdCgGQlpQNaUCUNa+DDAA5phmBQOmpA8p0+TCq0TQtKEASxAwtRQLaDpOhALrEaRy4eqOdz4KQAB0a4bkgADM26ZrSOa8RkB4AGZCEIx6cqJ+hIAg9BAb0miaBAYByAgmAgMA8oEUKABWOD4BSKDqIa0AmdAQj2Ph2YoCR8BcEAA)

---

Original answer for a union:

A simple solution could be to just build the desired union directly, with some members of the union being possibly `never` (in case they are not desired), instead of using chained conditional types (which indeed can return only a single result):

```
type AdditinalAttributes2<T> =
  | T extends TypeableInputs ? TypeableAttributes : never
  | T extends DropdownInputs ? DropdownAttributes : never
  | T extends NumericInputs ? NumericAttributes : never
```

We can even build a utility type to factorize the expression:

```
type Extends<T, I, A> = T extends I ? A : never

type AdditinalAttributes3<T> =
  | Extends<T, TypeableInputs, TypeableAttributes>
  // etc.
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEMBGAbCBJAdmArsAzlALxQDkmOAtkhAE6lQA+ZwEAHsKQFCiRQAitAPZgAJkIDumLLgLEy3XtAByVOgEsAxjLyF55KjXpce8WPGRoAgsGC11SPBEIlScSJYg27Dp-kVmgiLiUt72jqwuZEFikphhvpEBfKqUGpoJEc76qemZftymfFaiourA6pgIKPmRADwwAHzyABQmUB2wUOysmKKE7oioGNi6UAD8UFydM+Yew7XZAFztnTDdHBB9hDEh0qNyk9OzHbtxi4RLU8cd6z1b-VC59toHekcnHc9aFx0rN1AAN5QAC+XAAlCY0MAoJgkFcSmUKlUarZwn46gZqHRSI0uHD9INPBcGAB6UlQADyAGsECB8UgcmoXiSoOSoABRABKXMpXKugzIACJvhk0YlnEKGOpCJghDCEPh8OoAOZVYZQYBCTVmUhCokLcVZfBSgB0JiUnM22waABooOh7VZmiQ7tbHugJlArFArpgIAA3OgWsyI8qVaoXADMDRdx2YHPd+DtcyGaB0BHtBusRr8eI6CaTKbOUgz+HtJfiuci+aYVt6-RTorL9tFFzxXGhsKQACYEaVwyjo5iKNj6Hi4T3CRZDT5jWSKTS6Qyp6429XnAuqbT6ZP9JXWeyAGIIdQoKCKjaQTSsURQiAwuFR-tIiOoud+GOkAAWEBQKCEXEGSjad5hzD8kjZCkTzPC9CHYa9bwFXV8B8TAVWlWV5Tg5U1U8TVtUtchAxxc0gA)

Comment: Note how the question wants `AdditionalAttributes<"number">` to be `TypeableAttributes & NumericAttributes` and not `TypeableAttributes | NumericAttributes` (so those `XXXAttributes` types are also presumably objectlike and not distinct literals)

Comment: Indeed I just saw my misunderstanding :-S